# Does there exist some sort of classification of two-element minor-regular collections of graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-minors

Suppose $\mathfrak{F}$ is a finite collection of finite undirected simple graphs. Let’s call it minor-regular iff for any finite undirected simple graph $\Gamma$ it satisfies the condition:
If $\Gamma$ contains a graph from $\mathfrak{F}$ as a minor, then it contains a graph from $\mathfrak{F}$ (maybe a different one) as a topological minor.

One-element minor-regular collections of graphs are already classified:

> $\{\Gamma\}$ is minor-regular iff the degrees of all vertices $\Gamma$ do not exceed $3$

The proof that «the degrees of all vertices $\Gamma$ do not exceed $3$» implies «$\{\Gamma\}$ is minor-regular» can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1045985/407165). The inverse statement can be proved by contradiction using a construct from [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284026/407165).

My question is:

> Does there exist some sort of classification of two-element minor-regular collections?

Such collections can be formed as unions of pairs of the above collections (as the class of all minor-regular collections is closed under finite unions), however, that is not all:

> $\{K_5, K_{3, 3}\}$ is minor-regular

(a corollary of Wagner and Kuratowski theorems)

And there definitely should be something else…